# Xamarin.UITests Android Device Not Detected or Not Working

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin, nunit, ui-testing

I can't run Xamarin.UITests on any Android simulator/emulator. Any suggestions? I get the following errors when I try:

**Google Emulator:**

SetUp: System.Exception: Unable to run on a physical device without activation.
The full version is available for Xamarin Test Cloud customers, for more information contact sales@xamarin.com
If you are already a Xamarin Test Cloud customer, you can provide your api in one of the following ways:
* Adding it ConfigureApp using the ApiKey method
* Setting the XTC_API_KEY environment variable
* Adding the following attribute to your Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs file: [assembly: Xamarin.UITest.TestCloudApiKey(YOUR_API_KEY)]
* Place an xtc_api-key file containing your api key in an upstream directory from the test assembly

**Xamarin Android Player:**

SetUp: System.Exception: No devices connected

**GenyMotion:**

SetUp : System.Exception : Failed to execute: /users/erikandersen/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb devices - exit code: 1
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
adb server is out of date. Killing…

After updated GenyMotion to 2.3.1, I now get the following error:

SetUp: System.Exception: App Installation failed with output: 12050 KB/s (11199602 bytes in 0.907s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/final-xxxxxx.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]

**NUnit Code**

```
    AndroidApp _app;
    public string PathToAPK { get; set; }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void BeforeAll ()
    {
        var path = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
        var info = new FileInfo(path);
        var directory = info.Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName;

        PathToAPK = Path.Combine(directory, "Android", "bin", "Debug", "Demo.Android.apk");
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEach ()
    {
        _app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile (PathToAPK).StartApp ();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestInvalidEmail ()
    {
        _app.EnterText (c => c.Class ("UITextField"), "");
    }
```

TestInvalidEmail() is never called because NUnit fails on

```
_app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile (PathToAPK).StartApp ();
```

*Background:*

I'm using Xamarin.UITests for an iOS/Android application I'm developing and we're having issues with the Android side of things. iOS works fine. I've written each test twice, once in C# and once in Ruby using calabash, in order to isolate the issue. Calabash works fine, but any C# NUnit Test Project fails to connect to any emulator I try launching.

*What I've tried:*

1. Making sure an emulator is already running before I run the tests
2. Making sure only 1 emulator is running
3. Restarting the adb server
4. Trying multiple types of emulators (i.e. Xamarin Android Player, Gennymotion, and the Google Emulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after several hours of working on this, this fixed it:

1. **Upgrade GennyMotion to 2.3.1**
2. **Delete my old GenyMotion Simulator (Nexus 4) and create a new one**
3. **Add support for all ABIs in my Android Build settings**

Android Project > Options > Android Build > Advanced Tab > Supported ABIs > Check "armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86" > OK

4. **Generate a new .apk file via the terminal (while inside the Android project directory)**

/usr/bin/xbuild /t:Package /p:Configuration=Release .csproj

5. **Resigned the .apk via calabash-android**

calabash-android resign ./bin/Release/.apk

6. **In Xamarin Studio, set my Startup Project as the my UITest project**
7. **Launch GenyMotion simulator**
8. **Ran the tests under the Debug configuration with only the GenyMotion simulator active**

And it worked! I still can't run UI tests with the Google Emulator or the Xamarin Android Player. Funny thing is, I also can't debug my Android project using GenyMotion. It's only good for UITests. SO here's my current setup:

Xamarin Android Player - Normal debug

GenyMotion - UITests

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed by setting the ApiKey when setting ConfigureApp.

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
            _app = ConfigureApp.iOS.AppBundle(PathToIPA).ApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY_HERE").StartApp();
    }
```

As in [here](https://github.com/xamarin/mini-hacks/blob/master/Test%20Cloud/README.md). Just put your ApiKey there.

Note: I didn't have this problem with Xamarin Android Player. I didn't have this problem with AVD running an Android 5.0 emulator. I only had this problem with AVD running an Android 4.0.3 emulator.